# ¿Como ordenar de manera ascendente las vocales de una cadena?

Tags: java

Supongamos que ingreso la siguiente cadena:

```
"hola mundo"
```

¿Como podría ordenar únicamente las vocales de dicha cadena, pero de manera descendente?

a ejemplo:

```
"halo mondu"
```

De la siguiente manera eh tratado de dar solución al problema, pero cuando lo corro me dice que que tengo un exeptionBounce 5.
como podría corregirlo?
Tambien se me indica que la linea responsable es la siguiente:

if(cad[i].equalsIgnoreCase(vocal[j])

```
      private String[]cad;
      private String[]vocal={"a","e","i","o","u"};
      private String resp="";   
      private String aux="":
      private String []sort;
      private int cont=0;


public String ordenar(String cadena)
  {
     cad= cadena.split("");

     for(int i=0; i<cad.length; i++)
     {

       for(int j=0, j<vocal.length; j++)
         {

            if(cad[i].equalsIgnoreCase(vocal[j])
            {             

            aux+=cad[i];
            sort= aux.Split("");
            Arrays.sort(sort);

           for(int i=0; i<cad.legth; i++)
           {

             cad[i] = sort[k];
             resp+=cad[i];

           }
           }
        }
       }




   return resp;
}
```

Comment: buenas. puedes poner el codigo de lo que has probado hasta ahora, para ver si podemos ayudarte mejor? a mi se me ocurre de primeras usar un array auxiliar, en el que vamos añadiendo todas las vocales que encontremos en la frase; seguidamente ordenas el array de vocales;  luego recorres la frase y cada vez que encuentres una vocal, la cambias por la que tienes en el array de vocales. Cada vez que encuentres una, incrementas el indice (o borras el elemento del array) para ir añadiendo la siguiente

Comment: Por mas que estes en la universidad o donde sea, estas haciendo una pregunta, y la gente que se toma el trabajo de leer y comentarla necesita la informacion clara. El codigo debe ir en la pregunta. Cual es claramente el error de lo que te esta ocurriendo?

Comment: Me eh venido arriba con el código desde mi memoria, espero eso pueda servir...

Comment: @Jakala lo que as descrito es básicamente lo que eh intentado hacer sin éxito

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error en el for interno. Si usas i como variable para recorrer el for, estas anulando la i del for externo y por eso tenes el error que ves.

```
for(int i=0; i<cad.legth; i++)
{
    for(int j=0, j<vocal.legth; j++)
    {
        if(cad[i].equalsIgnoreCase(vocal[j])
            aux+=cad[i];
        sort= aux.Split("");
        Arrays.sort(sort);
        for(int i=0; i<cad.legth; i++)
        {
            cad[i] = sort[k];
            resp+=cad[i];
        }
   return resp;
}
```

Si ese es tu codigo, entonces es confuso y no estaria correcto. Fijate que las llaves no cierran como corresponde, y el if ejecuta solo una linea.

Comment: ademas, tiene mas errores, ya que esta llamando a `cad.legth`, que es incorrecto. seria `cad.length`. La logica no esta bien implementada, puesto que el tercer for anidado deberia estar FUERA del todo.

Comment: Si si.. no marque todo porque el codigo ni compila y deberiamos cerrar la pregunta como no reproducible...

Comment: tampoco lo veo asi... :) se ve que es alguien que esta estudiando y tiene bastantes conceptos que aclarar... Por favor @axwell-duarte, revisa un poco el codigo con las dos cosas que te hemos comentado, a ver si puedes avanzar un poco

Comment: el exception que te da seguro que es porque estas comparando un caracter `cad[i]` con una cadena `vocal[j]`, dado que vocal lo tienes definido como un `array` de strings. probablemente una solucion sea quitar los corchetes de la definicion de `vocal` ,`cad` y `sort` (que por cierto, es un mal nombre para una variable, ya que hay metodos que se llaman asi, y puedes confundirte)

Answer (score 0):

Yo voy a proceder a hacer el ordenamiento de una forma distinta, ya que con el código que he visto no comprendo como va a hacer la ordenación de las vocales exclusivamente.

Mi forma de proceder sera la siguiente:

- Recorremos el array
- Almacenamos en una lista cada vocal que se encuentra
- Almacenamos en otra lista la posición de la vocal (indice de esta)
- Terminado de recorrer el array, ordenamos la lista de vocales y procedemos a recolocarlas en el array inicial siguiendo las posiciones de la lista de posiciones.

Ah, y por cierto, mejor un arraylist a un array de Strings. Da muchas herramientas utiles que no tiene el array.

Ahora el código:

```
private String[]vocal={"a","e","i","o","u"};
private List<String> vocalList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(vocal));


public String ordenar(final String cadena)
{
 final List<String> vocales= new ArrayList();
 final List<Integer> posiciones = new ArrayList();
 String[]cad= cadena.split("");

 //Obtenemos los listados de vocales y posiciones
 for(final int i=0; i<cad.length; i++)
 {
   if(vocalList.contains(cad[i]))//Si es una vocal
   {
        vocales.add(cad[i]);
        posiciones.add(i);
   }
 }

 //Ordenamos el array de vocales de forma inversa
 Arrays.sort(vocales);

 //Recolocamos las vocales
 for(final int i=0;i<vocales.size();i++)
 {
    cad[posiciones.get(i)]=vocales.get(i);
 }

 //Transformamos el String[] a String
 String resp="";
 for(final int i=0; i<cad.length;i++)
 {
    resp+=cad[i];
 }

 return resp;
}
```

Espero que te sea útil.